# Check if row has any value if it has redirect

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I am trying to set an if statement on the page where you choose a " class " to play. What i want to check is if the row pathoption has any value set, and if it has redirect to the homepage and if it doesnt have any value set dont redirect. Currently im setting a username in the both the user and "stats" table on register. The problem i have is that it redirects to whatever i have set in the if statement.

Here is my code:

```
//CREATE CONNECTION
    $conn = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $db);
  $username = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
// CHECK CONNECTION
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}

$query = "SELECT pathoption from stats where username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    header('location:../../index.php?page=home');
}
```

Comment: You do not check if pathoption field has a value, you only check if the user has any records associated with in the stats table.

Comment: @Shadow Alright.. how would i check if the field pathoption from the logged in user has a value the correct way?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) only returns the number of rows in a result set, I'm assuming that you want to check if `pathoption` is empty or not, here is an example:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ( !empty($row['pathoption']) ) {
        header('location:../../index.php?page=home');
    }

}
```

Note: your code is vulnerable against SQL injection, You have to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, that redirects it to homepage with value is empty? Could you modify the code so that if the  row has a value it redirects to homepage?

Comment: Updated, I thought the opposite